# Certbot LetsEncrypt SSL certificate - use multiple configurators for one SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I want to create one SSL certificate for three domains that should be handled by the same nginx webserver.

```
example.com
cdn.example.com
example.external.com
```

The first is our main domain name, the second is the CDN. They are both on Amazon Route 53, but the CDN forwards to AWS cloudfront. I can create a LetsEncrypt SSL certificate with the Route-53 plugin for the first two.

The third domain name is not under my control but a simple DNS A-record that forwards to our server. I can use an nginx challenge okay, but certbot does not seem to allow both an nginx and letsencrypt cert request.

Has anyone managed to do this for one certificate? I don't think I can bypass the route-53 challenge because of the CDN. Or should I give up on the one-server setup and simply define different nginx hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to need two different certs.

You are authenticating the first two domains using a DNS challenge (in this case Route 53), which is great since the caching issue may prevent Let's Encrypt from using the HTTP-01 challenge.

The third domain's authentication MUST be done using HTTP-01 challenge since you cannot use a DNS challenge, since the domain doesn't belong to you.

It might be worth a shot to do HTTP-01 challenge for all three domains, though I'm worried the caching brought on by CloudFront might pose issues.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, turns out it was indeed the easiest route to add another server config with a dedicated SSL on a separate certbot challenge.